# Unexpected value of vector.back()

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I've been going out of my mind about this one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<int *> b;

    a.push_back(13);
    b.push_back(&a.back());

    a.push_back(24);
    b.push_back(&a.back());

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    for (std::vector<int *>::iterator it = b.begin(); it != b.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *(*it) << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
13 24
16712910 24
```

I'd really like to know, why both output lines do not match. What am I missing here? I have compiled this with gcc 4.6.3

Comment: Vector reallocates if new size > capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening due to the `vector` growing and reallocating the elements during the second `push_back`. When you do the second `push_back` it is possible that the vector finds that its capacity is full and allocates a new space and moves the elements to the new memory. It also frees the previously allocated memory. Since your are storing the address of this freed memory location, you see the garbage values. To solve this, you need to do `a.reserve(2)` so that vector doesn't reallocate during your push_back of 2 ints.

Answer (score 1):

The second call to `a.push_back()` may (and in this case obviously does) change the address of the first element in `a` by reallocation the whole amount of memory. Therefore `&a[0]` does not match the address which is stored in `b[0]` anymore.

Try:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> a;
  a.push_back(13);
  std::cout << &a[0] << endl;
  a.push_back(24);
  std::cout << &a[0] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You'll most likely see different values :)

Answer (score 0):

`vector` implements a *dynamic* array: when you `push_back`, the array may be reallocated — moved to another location in memory. But the values you're pushing into `b` won't be updated when the array owned by `a` is moved. They point to no-man's land, and accessing `b[0]` causes undefined behavior. In this case, a random value is read.

Answer (score 0):

if the initial (a) vector is re-sized the elements in b will point to invalid values.
In order to ensure that it works we'll have to know in advance the maximum elements we'll push in a and set the capacity before inserting elements.

Answer (score 0):

When inserting new elements into Vector and exceeding its capacity - it reallocates memory and all previously obtained direct references become corrupted because desired information is no longer there.